# How can I change the symbols to numbers in multi-authors in conference \IEEEauthorrefmark?

Tags: author, author-number, ieeeconf

How can I control the symbols of \IEEEauthorrefmark. I want to change these sumbols (*,|,+) to number (1,2,3).
The used code :

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author One\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Author Two\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, Author Three\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
Author Four\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Whatever,
Whichever University\\
Wherever\\
Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}author.one@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}author.two@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}author.three@add.on.net,
\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}author.four@add.on.net}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: If this is for an article submission, I'd advised against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to redefine `\IEEEauthorrefmark` since the representation is hardcoded inside the definition. An updated definition is presented below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

% Original definition
%\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize\ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or%
%    \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger%
%    \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\textsuperscript{\expandafter\romannumeral#1}\fi}}}}
%\fi
\DeclareRobustCommand{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{\smash{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize #1}}}

\begin{document}

\title{An Important Conference Contribution}

\author{%
  \IEEEauthorblockN{%
    Author One\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
    Author Two\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, 
    Author Three\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
    Author Four\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
  \IEEEauthorblockA{%
    Department of Whatever,
    Whichever University\\
    Wherever\\
    Email: \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}author.one@add.on.net,
      \IEEEauthorrefmark{2}author.two@add.on.net,
      \IEEEauthorrefmark{3}author.three@add.on.net,
      \IEEEauthorrefmark{4}author.four@add.on.net}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```